# SQL Server 2005 FullText index ''IX_on_an_identity_col is not a valid index to enforce a full-text search key...'

Tags: sql-server-2005, full-text-search

ok, got a problem creating a full text catalog.

This is the code I create my unique non nullable etc. index with

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_unique] ON [dbo].[my_table] 
(
    [my_identity_column] ASC
)
WITH (
    PAD_INDEX  = OFF, 
    STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
    SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
    IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
    DROP_EXISTING = OFF, 
    ONLINE = OFF, 
    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
    ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON, 
    FILLFACTOR = 90
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The column it's created on is a non nullable, identity column storing ints.

Running this then fails

```
EXEC sp_fulltext_table 
    @tabname='my_table', 
    @action='create', 
    @ftcat = 'my_catalog',  
    @keyname = 'IX_unique'
GO
```

With this message

```
'IX_unique' is not a valid index to enforce a full-text search key. A full-text search key must be a unique, non-nullable, single-column index which is not offline, is not defined on a non-deterministic or imprecise nonpersisted computed column, and has maximum size of 900 bytes. Choose another index for the full-text key.
```

Anyone got a clue? I've googled but the main mistake people seem to eb making is using  the column name instead of the index name.

Thanks,
Robin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**==SOLVED==**

Doh

You can't see it in the above as I tidied my sql to get rid of specific table names, at the same time I also removed the problem. The index was being created with a slightly different name from the index I was trying to reference when creating the Full Text index. Some indication of the actual problem from SQL Server would have been nice but I guess at the moment I'm in no great position to criticise another's work.

Guess I'll leave this as testament to my idiocy and so others can perhaps learn from it.